# Is there anyway in which I don't need to specify the linker when compiling?

Tags: linux, c++

For example, If my c++ code included `math.h` so that I can use `sin()`.

When I compile my code, I need to add the linker, that is :

```
g++ main.cpp -lm
```

So my question is: Is there any way in which I don't need to add the `-lm`?

Comment: No, you must specify the libraries to link to.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the `-lm` isn't the "linker" it's the name of a library you are asking to link against.

Secondly, the simple answer to your question is no, there isn't a way to avoid needing to specify that - if you use routines from a library other than the main C library then you need to tell the compiler that so it knows where to find the routines.

Comment: Well, you could invoke the compiler through a tool that specifies the libraries you need to link to for you. You'd need to configure that tool to pass `-lm` to the compiler, but you'd only need to do that once.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using [`make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and `Makefile`s. Of course you still need the links to libraries, but you don't need to think about it anymore when compiling. This comes in handy especially when you are linking multiple libraries.